# ng-pattern regular expression that starts with a lowercase or digit, also ends with a lowercase or digit

Tags: angularjs-validation

I cannot seem to figure out the correct pattern for input validation. I'm trying to allow for a string that begins with a lowercase letter or a number, ends with a lowercase or a number, and contains only lowercase letters, dots or dashes. I've got this so far
`ng-pattern="/^[a-z\d][a-z\d-.]*[a-z\d]$"` but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

So, while it is said that dots inside brackets are not special characters, it seems they are. When I added a backslash in front of the dot, my issue was fixed. So the regular expression is as follows `ng-pattern="/^[a-z\d][a-z\d\.-]*[a-z\d]$"`